# XSL: Can't get value to print once instead of multiple times

Tags: xml, xslt

so I have a class project I'm working on and I got it to a certain point but I need it to display one value instead of a value every time it comes across a student's name. It'll scan the document for a students name and when it finds it and what grade they have it writes it out as "1 2 3 4" instead of just "4".

Also if anyone could help me with getting it into percent form for the next part it'd be greatly appreciated!

XSL:

```
    <?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:variable name="total_students"/>
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <html>
            <head>
                <title>Grade Report</title>
            </head>
            <body>

                                <h2>A</h2>
                                Number of students receiving grade:
                <xsl:call-template name="print_grade">
                    <xsl:with-param name="target_grade" select="'A'"/>
                </xsl:call-template>
                                <p>Percentage of students receiving grade:</p>
                <p/>

                                <h2>B</h2>
                                Number of students receiving grade:
                <xsl:call-template name="print_grade">
                    <xsl:with-param name="target_grade" select="'B'"/>
                </xsl:call-template>
                                <p>Percentage of students receiving grade:</p>
                <p/>

                                <h2>C</h2>
                                Number of students receiving grade:
                <xsl:call-template name="print_grade">
                    <xsl:with-param name="target_grade" select="'C'"/>
                </xsl:call-template>
                                <p>Percentage of students receiving grade:</p>
                <p/>
            </body>
        </html>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template name="print_grade">
        <xsl:param name="pos" select="1"/>
        <xsl:param name="num" select="1"/>
        <xsl:param name="target_grade"/>
        <xsl:variable name="student" select="/class/student[grade=$target_grade][$pos]"/>
        <xsl:if test="$student">
            <td>
                <xsl:value-of select="$num"/>
            </td>
            <xsl:call-template name="print_grade">
                <xsl:with-param name="pos" select="$pos + 1"/>
                <xsl:with-param name="num" select="$num + 1"/>
                <xsl:with-param name="target_grade" select="$target_grade"/>
            </xsl:call-template>
        </xsl:if>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<?xml-stylesheet href="Project7.xsl" type="text/xsl"?>
<!-- XML Project 7 -->

<class>
<student>
    <first-name>Jane</first-name>
    <last-name>Doe</last-name>
    <grade>A</grade>
</student>
<student>
    <first-name>John</first-name>
    <last-name>Smith</last-name>
    <grade>B</grade>
</student>
<student>
    <first-name>Harry</first-name>
    <last-name>Grandson</last-name>
    <grade>A</grade>
</student>
<student>
    <first-name>Lacy</first-name>
    <last-name>Jones</last-name>
    <grade>B</grade>
</student>
<student>
    <first-name>Ulne</first-name>
    <last-name>Douglas</last-name>
    <grade>C</grade>
</student>
<student>
    <first-name>Ambrose</first-name>
    <last-name>Tyler</last-name>
    <grade>B</grade>
</student>
<student>
    <first-name>Roger</first-name>
    <last-name>Clemens</last-name>
    <grade>A</grade>
</student>
<student>
    <first-name>Monroe</first-name>
    <last-name>Hamburger</last-name>
    <grade>A</grade>
</student>
</class>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider using a key to look up `student` elements by their `grade`

```
<xsl:key name="student" match="student" use="grade" />
```

Then, to count the number of students of a particular grade, you can just do this

```
<xsl:value-of select="count(key('student', 'A'))" />
```

And your percentage calculation becomes this

```
<xsl:value-of select="count(key('student', 'A')) div count(/class/student) * 100" />
```

But....

You've got some repeated coding here, if you are going to specify "A", "B" and "C" separately. Is it just those three grades you want? What happens if a "D" comes along, or an "A*"?

Well, read up on a technique called [Muenchian Grouping](http://www.jenitennison.com/xslt/grouping/muenchian.html). Using this technique, you can get the distinct grades like so:

```
<xsl:for-each select="student[generate-id() = generate-id(key('student', grade)[1])]">
```

(Strictly speaking, you are getting student elements whose grades are the first occurrence of that particular grade in the XML)

Within this loop, the count of students is just this:

```
<xsl:value-of select="count(key('student', grade))" />
```

Try this XSLT

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
    <xsl:output method="html"  />
    <xsl:key name="student" match="student" use="grade" />

    <xsl:template match="/class">
      <hmtl>
        <head>
          <title>Grade Report</title>
        </head>
        <xsl:variable name="numberOfStudents" select="count(student)" />
        <xsl:for-each select="student[generate-id() = generate-id(key('student', grade)[1])]">
            <h2><xsl:value-of select="grade" /></h2>
            <p>
                <xsl:text>Number of students receiving grade: </xsl:text>
                <xsl:value-of select="count(key('student', grade))" />
            </p>
            <p>
                <xsl:text>%age of students receiving grade: </xsl:text>
                <xsl:value-of select="count(key('student', grade)) div $numberOfStudents * 100" />
            </p>
        </xsl:for-each>
      </hmtl>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Note also how the count of total students is in a variable, to avoid repeated calculation of that within the loop.

Comment: Thank you for breaking it down for me! Worked great! Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You are really close on this one, you're just missing a point. If you look at your query on the template:

```
<xsl:variable name="student" select="/class/student[grade=$target_grade][$pos]"/>
```

This will return an individual student. However:

```
<xsl:variable name="students" select="/class/student[grade=$target_grade]"/>
```

will return a nodeSet of *all* students with that grade.

```
<xsl:value-of select="count($students)"/>
```

will return the number of nodes in that set (ie the number of students with that grade).

Given that count (/class/student) gives you a list of all students, calculating a percentage should be really easy.

Comment: Thanks for the response, however I'm a little lost. I tried the last line of code to see if it would just come back once but now it comes back for each student. Like instead of saying "4" it says "1 1 1 1" How would I condense that into 4? Thanks!

Comment: Ignore your current print_grade template - over-complicated. The # of students with grade A = <xsl:value-of select="count(/class/student[grade='A'])"/>. Don't forget to use the count() function.